# Android View Binding for a "base fragment"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding

Android/Kotlin rookie here.
I'm converting someone else's code, that was written with synthetics, to View Bindings per Google Play's upcoming deprecation deadline. I read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities) and [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) and converted the obvious stuff, but:

The developer set up 2 fragments that use a "base fragment", like this:

```
class FragmentA: BaseFragment() { ... }
class FragmentB: BaseFragment() { ... }
and then
open class BaseFragment: Fragment() { ... }
```

The base fragment references views in layouts associated with fragments A/B, using synthetics. (She could do that because she broke the layouts of fragments A/B into reusable components, and those two fragments are mutually exclusive -- only one of them may run at any given moment. Each of those reusable layout components has a binding class, I can see them, but I cannot reference them inside the base fragment, they're not inflated.)

My question: How do I get rid of the synthetic references in the base fragment? (Worst case, I copy paste everything and get rid of the base fragment, but wonder if there's a way to retain the design.)

Many thanks

*7/21/23 adding some sample code per req. from @Obscure Cookie.*

All those (ostensibly undefined) variables in the code come from the layouts imported at the top using android.synthetic. BaseGamesFragment doesn't have a layout per-se. The fragments that are based on it inflate the layouts.

```
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_fib.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.games_top_panel.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.hints_panel_games.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.no_headset_container.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.song_panel.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

open class BaseGamesFragment : PitchBaseFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        startForResult =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {}
    }

    open fun initUI() {

        extra_button.setOnClickListener {
            try {
                // Exit games, then nav to settings
                val intent = Intent(activity, SettingsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    PSM.handleEvent(Event.SettingsButton93)
                }
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                Timber.e("LC: BaseGamesActivity initUI : %s", e.localizedMessage)
            }
        }

        btn_continue_anyway.setOnClickListener {
            displayDialog(no_headset_container, false)
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                // This is supposed to set the headsetSession to false
                PSM.handleEvent(Event.GenericFalse)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun updateSongPanel() {  // should be called song clock; just how deep we are into the song.
        song_panel?.let {
            SongLearningProgress.song?.let { currentSong ->
                currentLine?.let { currentLine ->
                    val (_, lyricsLine) = currentSong.findSectionAndLine(currentLine)
                    val startsAt = lyricsLine.startsAt.toInt()
                    song_progress_bar.progress = startsAt
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showBottomSheet() {
        main_debug_bottom_sheet_contents.show()
        main_debug_bottom_sheet_contents.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    open fun displayDialog(dialogType: String, visible: Boolean) {
        param = dialogType
        if (dialogType == "DNH1") {
            // display/hide no headset dialog
            if (visible) {
                view_flipper?.startFlipping()
            } else {
                view_flipper?.stopFlipping()
            }
            displayDialog(no_headset_container, visible)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best practice to create a BaseFragment as below so that you have a reference to the ViewBinding from BaseFragment.

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VBinding : ViewBinding, ViewModel : BaseViewModel> : Fragment() {

open var useSharedViewModel: Boolean = false

protected lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
protected abstract fun getViewModelClass(): Class<ViewModel>

protected lateinit var binding: VBinding
protected abstract fun getViewBinding(): VBinding

private val disposableContainer = CompositeDisposable()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    init()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setUpViews()
    observeData()
}

open fun setUpViews() {}

open fun observeView() {}

open fun observeData() {}

private fun init() {
    binding = getViewBinding()
    viewModel = if (useSharedViewModel) {
        ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(
            getViewModelClass()
        )
    } else {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(getViewModelClass())
    }
}

fun Disposable.addToContainer() = disposableContainer.add(this)

override fun onDestroyView() {
    disposableContainer.clear()
    super.onDestroyView()
}}
```

[link](https://dev.to/enyason/how-to-set-up-a-base-fragment-class-with-viewbinding-and-viewmodel-on-android-57g1)

Comment: Thank you @ByteCode. This seems a bit over my paygrade (near zero experience with Android) so I'm going to move the layout references out of that base fragment and be done with it. It looks like much of the code I struggle with is really logic that updates things on the screen. I think I'm going to extract those into a domain object file, pass the binding class to it and call it a day?